# How to Diagnose CarrierWave "undefined method `scale' for #<ImageUploader:..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to use CarrierWave with RMagick, but when I attempt to do any image manipulation (such as scale), I get undefined errors. (rails 4.0, ruby 2.0)

```
version :thumb do
    process :scale => [50, 50]
end
```

leads to...
    undefined method `scale' for #

I know I have imagemagick installed properly on my machine because I can run mogrify from the CLI.

Any ideas on how to diagnose the problem? I've tried many SO "solutions" with no luck

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I didn't find any reasonable solution to CarrierWave. Rather, it seems my ImageMagick install was somehow bad. Although it worked fine on the CLI, RMagick couldn't communicate properly. A clean reinstall of ImageMagick fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define a scale method? The one from the example is an empty method.

See [this discussion on this error on the Carrierwave github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/749).

Comment: I did, in fact, try others, including `process resize_to_fill: [210, 210]` with no success, but for different reasons (model fails to save)

Answer (score 2):

You might have missed following in your uploader class.

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```